# Is HTML Agility Pack for .net thread safe for read-only access using a single HtmlDocument instance across parallel threads?

Tags: c#, .net, html, web-scraping

Is HTML Agility Pack for .net thread safe for read-only access using a single HtmlDocument instance across parallel threads?

I am scraping a single page but scraping some parts of page for how I need the data can be slow so I want to scrape multiple sections of the page at one time using Parallel c# library.

Answer (score -1):

I've used HTMLAgilityPack in my multithreading program and it works fine.
I think you only need to safe your program by using some methods like locking blocks.

e.g
    lock(asyncObject)
    {
       // do html processing...
    }

Comment: well yea I know I can lock. I was trying to avoid that if I can.