# Is HtmlAgilityPack library is thread safe?

Tags: c#

I have to work with parallel threads to parse html nodes using HtmlAgilityPack library. I just want to know that is it safe to use this library in parallel threads?

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474534/is-html-agility-pack-for-net-thread-safe-for-read-only-access-using-a-single-ht

Comment: If you are just reading the content then I think you don't need to think about thread safety.

Comment: I need to perform read, add, update and remove operations on html nodes using HtmlAgilityPack library.